# Set value of hidden input inside form

Tags: javascript

I have next input on form (id of form = "form" for the example):
**as you can see, i set name and id.**

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="referer" id="referrer" />
```

I tried next thing on head:

```
<script>
 function start() {
var ref = document.getElementById('referrer');
ref.value = document.referrer;
}
onload = start;
</script>
```

But nothing, value="". i guess its because the input is on form ? if its the cause, how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

`window.onload` instead of `onload` seems to be the problem.

Tested the code [here](http://jsbin.com/zisilaku/1/edit).

Comment: From some reason - the hidden input still not get the referrer value.

Comment: @nicael thanks, its alert it good but hidden field is still "" value.
http://global2.globalvalyou.co.il/

Comment: @Oshrib Er.. I.. Whats language is this?

Comment: (i removed the alert).

Comment: @nicael hebrew :) but what important is view source nop? :)

Comment: it look like the alert sending the var value, and the input not working.